# D3 Geo Tile Baselayer Offset

Tags: d3.js, tile

I'm using d3.geo.tile() and have used it successfully before but this time the tile layer doesn't seem to draw at the same scale and translate as the point layer. The below code creates a map that pans and draws just fine, but draws the circles, which should be in the Mediterranean, in Africa. If I zoom in, it scales the tiles and circles just fine, it's as if my xy coordinates are off, but they aren't.

I get the feeling that it's actually drawing the base layer without offsetting and scaling it properly because it should be centering on the coordinates 12,42, but it's a great big mystery to me since this exact same code works fine in a different application.

If someone can spot some problem, or just a hint, that would help.

```
function createNewMap(){
 width = 1200, height = 800;
 var tile = d3.geo.tile()
  .size([1200, 800]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale((1 << 12) / 2 / Math.PI)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var center = projection([12, 42]);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
 .scale(projection.scale() * 2 * Math.PI)
 .scaleExtent([1 << 10, 1 << 17])
 .translate([width - center[0], height - center[1]])
 .on("zoom", zoomed);

projection
 .scale(1 / 2 / Math.PI)
 .translate([0, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("#newMapId").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .call(zoom);

 var raster = svg.append("g");
 var vector = svg.append("g");

 vector.selectAll("g").data(dataModule.polisData).enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "sites")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + (projection([d.xcoord,d.ycoord])[0]) + "," + (projection([d.xcoord,d.ycoord])[1]) + ")scale("+(projection.scale())+")"})
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "sitecirc");

  zoomed();

 function zoomed() {
  var tiles = tile
   .scale(zoom.scale())
   .translate(zoom.translate())
   ();

  var image = raster
   .attr("transform", "scale(" + tiles.scale + ")translate(" + tiles.translate + ")")
   .selectAll("image")
   .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

  image.exit()
   .remove();

  image.enter().append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + ["a", "b", "c", "d"][Math.random() * 4 | 0] + ".tiles.mapbox.com/v3/elijahmeeks.map-zm593ocx/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
   .attr("width", 1)
   .attr("height", 1)
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0]; })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1]; });

  vector
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + zoom.translate() + ")scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")");

  d3.selectAll(".sitecirc")
   .attr("r", 10 / zoom.scale());

 }
```

[image: Points are appended and projected correctly, base layer doesn't seem to scale and translate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be based on my example that changes the [SVG transform on zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5914438). Changing the transform is a nice technique when you have complex geometry that you just want to scale and translate when you pan or zoom — it’s typically faster than reprojecting everything — but it’s also more complex than [changing the projection on zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5342063).

The code doesn’t change very much if you want to change the projection on zoom. In essence:

```
projection
    .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate(zoom.translate());
```

And then re-run your d3.geo.path to re-render. As shown in [bl.ocks.org/9535021](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9535021):

[image: u.s. state capitals]

Also, fixing the projection and changing the transform can cause precision problems if you zoom in a lot. Another reason to only use that technique when it offers substantial performance gains by avoid reprojection. And here reprojecting is super-cheap because it’s just a handful of points.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the example, I'm sure it will prove useful for people, but even using the reproject method, I still end up with my baselayer being uncentered. The lat/long for the sites are correct, but there's obviously something somewhere else in the code for this application that is corrupting/interrupting the initial setting of the translate (but not the scale) of the tiles.

Comment: There’s likely some other issue with your code that cannot be investigated because you haven’t posted all your code & data. My example demonstrates how to draw vector points on top of raster tiles, and thus answers your question, even if it doesn't address whatever other issue (or issues) remain. Open-ended questions like “fix my code” aren’t a great fit for Stack Overflow—it’s better to ask something more specific, which is how I interpreted your question.

Comment: I know, but the application is one that I'm unfamiliar with, and so I can only deal with the graphical results on the map-side and the little bit of code I used. It was my hope that there was some known issue that the image would act as a visual cue for, like, "The tiles don't get initially centered if there's something that's overwritten variable X" but I knew that this was a bad question, and unlikely to have an answer.

Comment: Unless you’re able to reproduce this problem in an example we can run in a browser, you’re unlikely to get any helpful responses.